# In JHipster 7.1.0 + React, How to update the i18n with the current user's lanKey when the user logs in?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, jhipster, redux-toolkit

I created a new application with JHipster 7.1.0 and React with two languages: English and French. The default language is English. When the user logs in, I want to update the system language with the current user langKey (for example 'fr'). In `app.tsx`, I have tried the following:

```
import { setLocale } from 'app/shared/reducers/locale';
.
.
.


const currentLocale = useAppSelector(state => state.locale.currentLocale);
const isAuthenticated = useAppSelector(state => state.authentication.isAuthenticated);
const currentUser = useAppSelector(state => state.authentication.account);

useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated){
      setLocale(currentUser.langKey);
      // or
      currentLocale = currentUser.langKey;
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Please can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to dispatch that:

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated){
      dispatch(setLocale(currentUser.langKey));
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to do it: In loign.tsx I added

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated){
      if (Storage.session.get(`locale`)) {
        Storage.session.remove(`locale`);
      }
      dispatch(setLocale(account.langKey));
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);
```